# Enable in-place edit for cell in GridControl

Tags: wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I would like to enable in-place editing for cells in my GridControl. I have set property  AllowEditing on TableView and Columns, but data in my cells still cannot be edited after doubleclick on cell. Only "copy" is enabled in context menu. I failed to find a solution.

NavigationStyle property in TableView is set to "Cell"

My xaml.

```xml
    <dx:PLinqInstantFeedbackDataSource x:Name="PLinqInstantFeedbackDataSource" ListSource="{Binding Path=TestCollectionSource}" DefaultSorting="Property1 ASC"/>
    <dxg:GridControl EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data, ElementName=PLinqInstantFeedbackDataSource}" SelectionMode="Cell" IsManipulationEnabled="True">
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowEditing="True" NavigationStyle="Cell" AllowFilterEditor="True" AlternateRowBackground="CornflowerBlue" ShowAutoFilterRow="True" />
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Property1" AllowEditing="True" ReadOnly="False" />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Number" AllowEditing="True" ReadOnly="False" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

**EDIT**

ViewModel and ListSource class

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {

    }

    private BindingList<TestClass> testCollection;
    public BindingList<TestClass> TestCollection
    {
        get
        {
            var result = this.testCollection;
            if (null == result)
            {
                lock(this)
                {
                    result = this.testCollection;
                    if (null == result)
                    {
                        result = new BindingList<TestClass>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                        {
                            result.Add(new TestClass() { Property1 = "test" + i, Number = i % 20 });
                        }

                        this.testCollection = result;
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public IListSource TestCollectionSource
    {
        get { return new ListSource( ()=> this.TestCollection); }
    }
}
public class ListSource : IListSource
{
    public readonly Func<IList> innerListProvider;
    public ListSource(Func<IList> innerListProvider)
    {
        this.innerListProvider = innerListProvider;
    }
    public IList GetList()
    {
        return this.innerListProvider();
    }

    public bool ContainsListCollection
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}

public class TestClass : ObservableObject
{
    private string property1;
    public string Property1
    {
        get { return this.property1; }
        set
        {
            this.property1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Property1);
        }
    }

    private int number;
    public int Number
    {
        get { return this.number; }
        set
        {
            this.number = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is GridControl a custom DataGrid?

Comment: @AmitRaz GridControl is DataGrid from devexpress's wpf library.

Comment: What is your `TestCollectioSource`? Can you provide the code?

Comment: @nempoBu4 yes. see the edit. It's really simple. My xaml is MainWindow. I have provided MainWindowViewModel and ListSource class I created.

Comment: Can you also add the code for `TestClass`?

Comment: @nempoBu4 done. ObservableObject is implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got an [answer](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T202080) from DevExpress support.

> PLinqInstantFeedbackDataSource is a read-only data source. If you wish to edit data directly in the grid, bind your source collection to the GridControl.ItemsSource property without using an Instant Feedback data provider.

Answer (score 0):

My problem got fixed by setting `NavigationStyle="Row"` to `NavigationStyle="Cell"`